# Синонимизировать метки на тему [геометрия]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Нужно синонимизировать метки

- [geometry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) (13 вопросов)
- [геометрия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f) (444 вопроса)

*(у обеих есть описание)*

Основная - конечно, [геометрия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f), т. к. она на русском и с ней гораздо больше вопросов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 20 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 13 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 13 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'geometry': [geometry] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 457
tag remapping of [геометрия] and [geometry] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym geometry -> геометрия was approved!
```